# Google Cloud Composer: Access StatsD metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm running Google Cloud Composer with Airflow v1.10.3.

Per the Airflow v1.10.3 [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.3/metrics.html), StatsD metrics are available with the install of the StatD add-on. I also noticed that the StatD config is present in the airflow.cfg in the composer environment.

`gsutil cat gs://mycomposerbucket/airflow.cfg`

```
>>...

[scheduler]
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = airflow-monitoring-service.default.svc.cluster.local
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow

...
```

Does this mean I should be able to access the metrics in Composer somehow? I haven't been able to find these metrics in the StackDriver streaming Composer logs. Does anyone know where/how I can access/enable the metrics. I would like to build some alerts off of some of them.

Comment: This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments#using_on_environments) explains how you can examine Airflow metrics and create alerts.

Answer (score 1):

I spent probably half-a-day trying to figure out why I could not find the metrics. It turns out the majority of the metrics are not available until "Composer version 1.10.0 or higher and Airflow version 1.10.6". I was on Airflow v1.10.3. I upgraded the Composer environment and can now see them.

Hopefully this helps someone else. Lesson learned to always follow the footnotes in the Google Documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/monitoring-dashboard